Autocomplete Fails for File Paths in Argparse Without Virtual Environment
I'm encountering an issue with file path autocompletion in my Python script that uses the argparse module with several nested subparsers. I have enabled autocompletion using argcomplete, but instead of suggesting file paths, it suggests other optional parameters.
The structure of my subparsers is as follows:
metaOp.py  [--version] [-h]
├─┬╴local [-h]
│ ├─┬╴org [-h]
│ │ ├─╴mkOrg --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [-f] [-h] [-n]
│ │ ├─╴cleanOrg --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [-h]
│ │ ╰─╴openOrg --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [-h]
│ ╰─┬╴package [-h]
│   ├─╴mkPack --name NAME [--delSrc DelSrc...DelSrc_N] [--src Src...Src_N] [-h]
│   ├─╴sortPack --xml Xml1...XmlN [--inplace] [-h] [-o]
│   ╰─╴filterPack --xml Xml1...XmlN [--inplace] [-h] [-l] [-o]
├─┬╴get [-h]
│ ├─╴retrieve --alias Alias_1...Alias_N -p package.xml [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [-h]
│ ├─╴resList --alias Alias_1...Alias_N -t TYPE [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [-h]
│ ├─╴metaList --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [--ignore IGNORE] [-h]
│ ╰─╴report --alias Alias_1...Alias_N -j JOB_ID [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [-h]
├─┬╴cmp [-h]
│ ├─╴orgs --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [-f] [-h]
│ ╰─╴packages --xml Xml1...XmlN [-h]
╰─┬╴send [-h]
  ├─╴validate --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [--pack] [-h] [-t Min]
  ├─╴deploy --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [--pack] [-h] [-t Min]
  ├─╴runTest --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [--pack] [-h] [-t Min]
  ╰─╴quickDeploy --alias Alias_1...Alias_N [--base-org OrgBaseDir] [-h] [-t Min]

All parameters that require a path are defined in the final parsers. For example, the --base-org parameter should accept a path as input, but the autocompletion isn't working as expected.
Here's what I've done so far:
1. Installed argcomplete and enabled autocompletion in my script.
2. Used the activate-global-python-argcomplete command to enable global autocompletion.
3. Checked my shell configuration and restarted the terminal.
Despite these steps, autocompletion suggests other optional parameters instead of paths. Has anyone else experienced this issue or knows how to resolve it?
I detect this problem boot in bash terminal and zsh terminal
Thanks in advance for any help!

Update:
I’ve managed to replicate the issue with file path autocompletion in my Python script that uses argparse with nested subparsers. Initially, the autocompletion was suggesting other optional parameters instead of file paths.
While writing the example scripts, I noticed that activating a virtual environment based on Python 3.12.3 resolved the issue. However, after deactivating the virtual environment and returning to the global Python installation, the problem reappeared. I believe this information might be crucial for troubleshooting.
Below are the scripts I’ve been working with:
Python Script:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK

import argparse
import argcomplete

def main():
    # Main parser definition
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example of argparse with subcommands.")
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', help='Available subcommands')
    # 'single' subcommand
    parser_single = subparsers.add_parser('single', help='Handles a single file path')
    parser_single.add_argument("--single-path", type=str, help="A single file path.", required=True)
    parser_single.add_argument("--verbose", action="store_true", help="Enables verbose mode.", required=False)
    parser_single.add_argument("--timeout", type=int, help="Sets a timeout in seconds.", required=False)
    # 'multiple' subcommand
    parser_multiple = subparsers.add_parser('multiple', help='Handles a list of file paths')
    parser_multiple.add_argument("--multiple-paths", type=str, nargs='*', help="A list of file paths.", required=True)
    parser_multiple.add_argument("--recursive", action="store_true", help="Searches files recursively.", required=False)
    parser_multiple.add_argument("--log-level", type=str, choices=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL'], help="Sets the logging level.", required=False)
    # Enabling autocompletion
    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
    # Parsing known arguments
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    # Logic based on the chosen subcommand
    if args.command == 'single':
        print(f"You have chosen the 'single' subcommand with the path: {args.single_path}")
        if args.verbose:
            print("Verbose mode activated.")
        if args.timeout is not None:
            print(f"Timeout set to {args.timeout} seconds.")
    elif args.command == 'multiple':
        print(f"You have chosen the 'multiple' subcommand with the paths: {args.multiple_paths}")
        if args.recursive:
            print("Recursive search activated.")
        if args.log_level:
            print(f"Log level set to {args.log_level}.")
    else:
        print("Please choose a subcommand.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Bash Script:
#!/bin/bash
# Number of directories and files per directory
num_directories=5
num_files_per_directory=3
# Creating directories and files
for (( i=1; i<=num_directories; i++ )); do
    dir_name="Directory_$i"
    mkdir -p "$dir_name" # Creates the directory if it doesn't exist
    for (( j=1; j<=num_files_per_directory; j++ )); do
        file_name="$dir_name/File_$j.txt"
        echo "Hello $j" > "$file_name"
    done
done
echo "Directories and files created successfully."

I hope this additional information helps in diagnosing the problem. If anyone has insights or solutions, your input would be greatly appreciated.

To get an answer here, I think you should reduce this to a simple, reproducible example, showing the Python code which uses argparse and autocomplete, and how you request user input so that autocomplete can kick in.Note also that the description for autocomplete assumes that you are using bash, so I would leave out zsh from this discussion.

Post now script to reproduce. Note: During the writing of current test, i notice at the end, the problem was fixed after the activation of python venv in terminal

So, we can conclude from this, that the behaviour depends on the Python version, which is used to run the program, right?

I don't think so because the venv on which it works was created starting from the same global python, and with pip I had installed these libraries at a global level on purpose.
I'm not sure, but it almost seems like a bug, but I couldn't say when it was introduced.
